# Is there an elegant way to target a series of nested elements?

Tags: html, css

I have to style a widget in a web-based app and it is a front-end-developer's nightmare of nested divs:

```
<div id="outer">
  <h3>Title stuff</h3>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div id="inner">
            <div>Elements that shouldn't inherit any stuff from those ugly nested divs</div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>Prev</button>
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the middle divs - the ones with no class or id between `#outer` and `#inner` - to have a style that stops being inherited at `#inner`.

The only thing I could come up with was this:

```
#outer > div,
#outer > div > div,
#outer > div > div > div,
#outer > div > div > div > div { display: inline; }
```

That's hideous. Is there some slicker way to do this?

Comment: Do you want like this?  http://jsbin.com/wuwideyeho/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yep. I was over thinking it. Thanks panther and @braks. Time to call it a day, clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set all children `div`s `inline` and then `#inner` as block.

```
#outer div {display: inline;}
#outer #inner, #inner div {display: block}
```

**EDIT**:
Due to the comment below,

```
#inner {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 5em);
    display: block;

    div {display: block;}
}
```

Comment: No, because any divs inside of #inner will keep inheriting {display: inline;}

Comment: @NicoleMorganErickson: just try it. First line set all children `display: inline`, the second one `display: block` to `#inner`. It's exactly what you wanted.

Comment: so add `#outer #inner div` to the second one

Comment: @NicoleMorganErickson: you added other `div`s into `#inner`. I've updated my answer. You wanted to style one HTML markup and then you change to another one.

Comment: @panther See my codepen: http://codepen.io/nericksx/pen/MwaJra?editors=110  Any divs inside #inner inherit from #outer div {display: inline;}

Yeah sorry - I realized it wasn't clear.

Comment: @NicoleMorganErickson: add `div {}` into the `#inner` block - see my answer once again, I've made there another update.

Comment: Asked Question and given Answer there is no any co-relations. I was looking at this thread but didn't understand why use `calc` unless I read comments. OP problem solved but not friendly answer for people looking same answer in future.

Comment: @KheemaPandey: it's a part of code from the 5th comment to this answer, where is link to codepen. I think the OP wasn't able to put styles from my answer into LESS or what it is.